# Plot all real and imaginary roots of FindRoot vrs `k`

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, data

I'm looking to plot all real and imaginary roots of this cubic equation

```
eq[x_,k_]:=x^3-5x^2+x-k
```

as a function of a real parameter `k`.

**Step 1:** to get an idea, I first compare solutions by the two functions `NSolve` and `FindRoot` with a given range, for that I use

```
root1[k_]:= Solve[eq[x,k] == 0,x,Cubics->True]    

(* For k=2, root1[2] gives : {{{x -> 4.879057633484047},{x -> 0.06047118325797629 + 0.6373840752906359 I},
{x -> 0.06047118325797629 - 0.6373840752906359 I}}} *)

root2[k_]:= FindRoot[eq[x,k] == 0,{x,#}]&/@{-5,-2,0,2,5,10}

(* For k=2, root2[2] gives : {{{x -> 0.1031932441958189}, {x -> 0.1031957295973283}, {x -> 
0.1031928872111299}, {x -> 0.1031958817666505}, {x -> 
4.879057633484048}, {x -> 4.879057633484049}}}  *)
```

The problem at this level is that for the same value of `k=2` I can't find the same complex roots by `FindRoot`, why?

**Step 2:** Then I try to plot all real parts `Re[root2[k]] vrs k` and all imaginary parts `Im[root2[k]] vrs k` of solutions, I form a table `{k,root1[k]}` for `k∈[-5,5]` but then I don't know how to do it

```
data=Table[{k,root1[k]},{k,-5,5,1}]//N

(* {{-5., {{x -> 
 4.536629621205803 + 0. I}, {x -> -0.8434044873336737 + 
  2.220446049250313*10^-16 I}, {x -> 
 1.306774866127871 - 2.220446049250313*10^-16 I}}}, {-4., {{x -> 
 4.592614742039923 + 
  1.480297366166875*10^-16 I}, {x -> -0.7515320715475298 + 
  2.220446049250313*10^-16 I}, {x -> 
 1.158917329507606 - 2.220446049250313*10^-16 I}}}, {-3., {{x -> 
 1.}, {x -> -0.6457513110645907}, {x -> 
 4.645751311064591}}}, {-2., {{x -> 
 4.696392779347097 + 
  7.401486830834377*10^-17 I}, {x -> -0.518198699326341 + 
  4.440892098500626*10^-16 I}, {x -> 
 0.8218059199792439 - 4.440892098500626*10^-16 I}}}, {-1., {{x -> 
 4.744826077681923 + 
  3.700743415417188*10^-17 I}, {x -> -0.3488942175007166 + 
  4.440892098500626*10^-16 I}, {x -> 
 0.6040681398187938 - 4.440892098500626*10^-16 I}}}, {0., {{x -> 
 0.}, {x -> 0.2087121525220801}, {x -> 
 4.79128784747792}}}, {1., {{x -> 
 0.08201204045934052 + 0.4472778999095655 I}, {x -> 
 0.08201204045934052 - 0.4472778999095655 I}, {x -> 
 4.835975919081319}}}, {2., {{x -> 4.879057633484047}, {x -> 
 0.06047118325797629 + 0.6373840752906359 I}, {x -> 
 0.06047118325797629 - 0.6373840752906359 I}}}, {3., {{x -> 
 4.920676006565271}, {x -> 
 0.03966199671736437 + 0.7798071907703745 I}, {x -> 
 0.03966199671736437 - 0.7798071907703745 I}}}, {4., {{x -> 
 4.960954381704582}, {x -> 
 0.0195228091477091 + 0.8977278700998234 I}, {x -> 
 0.0195228091477091 - 0.8977278700998234 I}}}, {5., {{x -> 
 0. - 1. I}, {x -> 0. + 1. I}, {x -> 5.}}}} *)
```

How to do it please?

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq[x_, k_] := x^3 - 5 x^2 + x - k

root1[k_] = SolveValues[eq[x, k] == 0, x] // Simplify;

sol1 = root1[2] // N

(* {4.87906, 0.0604712 + 0.637384 I, 0.0604712 - 0.637384 I} *)
```

From the documentation, "If all equations and starting values are real, then FindRoot will search only for real roots . If any are complex, it will also search for complex roots ."

```
root2[k_] := 
 Flatten[Values /@ (FindRoot[eq[x, k] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {5, 0.1 + 0.7 I, 
      0.1 - 0.7 I})]

sol2 = root2[2]

(* {4.87906, 0.0604712 + 0.637384 I, 0.0604712 - 0.637384 I} *)

sol1 - sol2

(* {-8.88178*10^-16, 6.245*10^-17 - 3.33067*10^-16 I, 
 6.245*10^-17 + 3.33067*10^-16 I} *)

reim[k_] = ComplexExpand[ReIm[root1[k]]] // Simplify;

Show[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@reim[k], {k, -5, 5},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15],
 Graphics[{
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[ReIm[sol1]]}],
 AxesLabel -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Plotting `Re` and `Im` separately,

```
Column[
 Plot[
    Evaluate@#@root1@k, {k, -5, 5},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Dashed},
    PlotLabel -> #,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    PlotPoints -> 75,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@ {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[root2];
root2[k_, init : _List :
   {5, (1 + 7 I)/10, (1 - 7 I)/10}] :=
 Flatten[Values /@ (
    FindRoot[eq[x, k] == 0, {x, #}] & /@
     init)]

Column[
 ListLinePlot[
    #@Transpose@Table[root2[k,
        Piecewise[{{{9/2, 1/2, -1/2}, k <= 0},
          {{9/2, I/2, -I/2}, k > 0}}]],
       {k, -5, 5, 1/20}],
    DataRange -> {-5, 5},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Dashed},
    PlotLabel -> #,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@
  {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

Clear["Global`*"]

**EDIT 2:** Re the comment

`FindRoot`requires tailored starting values. You cannot blindly reuse a previous solution.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq[x_, k_] = 1 - k^2/x^2 - 1/(x(x - 20));

root1[k_] = SolveValues[
  {eq[x, k] == 0, -5 <= k <= 5}, x] // Simplify;

Column[
 Plot[
    Evaluate@#@root1@k, {k, -5, 5},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle ->
     {Green, {Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dotted}},
    PlotLabel -> #,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    PlotPoints -> 75,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@ {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

Since one of the roots is essentially constant, avoid taking its derivative. From the documentation, "FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, x0, x1}] searches for a solution using x0 and x1 as the first two values of x, avoiding the use of derivatives."

```
root2[k_] := Flatten[
  Values /@ (
    FindRoot[eq[x, k] == 0, {x, # - 10^-3, # + 10^-3}] & /@
     Piecewise[{{{20, k, -k}, k <= 0},
       {{20, -k, k}, k > 0}}])]

Column[
  ListLinePlot[
     #@Transpose@
       Table[root2[k], {k, -5, 5, 1/20}],
     DataRange -> {-5, 5},
     PlotStyle ->
      {Green, {Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dotted}},
     PlotLabel -> #,
     PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@
   {Re, Im}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Bob Hanlon, please I want to plot all `Re[root2[k]]` vrs `k`  and all `Im[root2[k]]` vrs `k`  in separated figures. How to do it?

Comment: @ BobHanlon, I didn't understand your plot. Please can you plot : `Re[root2[k]]: {4.87906, 0.0604712 , 0.0604712}` vrs`k` and `Im[root2[k]]: {0, 0.637384,- 0.637384}` vrs `k` separately.

Comment: @ BobHanlon, thank you so much.

Comment: @ BobHanlon, can you give me your email please to contact you privately?

Comment: @ BobHanlon, please how to contact you privately?

Comment: @ BobHanlon, I tried to apply the same reasoning for the equation $$1-\dfrac{k^2}{x^2} -\dfrac{1}{x(x - 20)}= 0
$$
 `eq[x_,k_]=1-(k^2/x^2)-(1/(x(x - 20)))=0`, however it works fine for root1 with `SolveValues` but not for root2 with `FindRoot`, what's wrong please?

Comment: @ BobHanlon thanks again, I'm very grateful. It's important for me to understand your code, please can you explain me why you use `Piecewise[{{{20, k, -k}, k <= 0},{{20, -k, k}, k > 0}}]` in `FindRoot`? This is my email : *betatron23@gmail.com*, please can you contact me privately?

Comment: `root2[k_] := Flatten[Values /@ (FindRoot[eq[x, k] == 0, {x, # - 10^-3, # + 10^-3}] & /@ {20, k, -k})]` would give essentially the same plots; however, the insight into branch behavior shown with `root1` is lost.

Comment: @ BobHanlon, so this is to show all the branches, excellent code, thank you very much. Please I will need your help on the same subject in private, can you send me an email at *betatron23@gmail.com*?

Comment: If you have additional questions ask them on this or similar forums

Comment: My real problem @Bob Hanlon arises in the resolution of this complex equation, which contains an integral: `eq[x_,k_,z_,a_] :=1 - (k^2/x^2) - (z^2/(2 BesselK[2, z] k^2)) NIntegrate[s  Sqrt[s^2 - 1] ((1 + (a/x)) - Sqrt[s^2/(s^2 - 1)] (x/k) ((1 + (a/x))^2 - ((s^2 - 1)/s^2) (k^2/x^2)) ArcTanh[Sqrt[(s^2 - 1)/s^2] (k/x)/(1 + (a/x))]) Exp[-z s], {s,1,Infinity}] = 0` By the way, I was looking for an easy method as your code that could to compute all the roots `Re[x]` and `Im[x]`  of `x` for a given parameters `k`, `z` and `a`, with `0.001 =< z =< 1000`, `0 =< k =< 100`, `a = 25`.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Bob Hanlon I could not since I'm a beginner in numerical resolution of algebraic equations. So if you can help me, I would be very grateful again.

Comment: Hi @BobHanlon, please are you here?

Comment: As I said earlier, "If you have additional questions ask them on this or similar forums" Do not ask additional questions in comments.

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon, so I will create a new post, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @BobHanlon, this is my new post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279693/58233